# seeing extra elements in developer tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

code :

```
<li> 
    <a href="#" id="CustomDecor">
        <ul id="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#" id="Carpets"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Storage_Solutions"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Flooring"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Interior_Painting"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Kitchen_Cabinet_Refacing"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Shutters"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Window_Treatments"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Window_Blinds"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

Developer tools :

[image]

Why am I seeing extra elements? (under `sub_menu` and first `li` of `sub_menu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest anchor (`<a>`) elements.
On encounter of a new anchor tag, the browser attempts to fix the structure, possibly by closing the previous tag.

Have a look at this simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZr3Z/

```
<li> 
    <a href="#" id="CustomDecor">                  <----- Anchor 1
        <ul id="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#" id="Carpets"></a></li> <----- Anchor 2
```

Comment: where exactly? it would help if you could elaborate, new to html

Comment: @akriy What exactely do you not understand?